# Keyboard shortcut for publishing a specific org-mode project

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

Following [this guide](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html), I have setup an org-mode project "foo" that I want to (frequently) publish using a single keyboard short.

Currently I have defined

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-1") 'org-publish)
```

so after typing C-c C-1, I still have to fill the prompt with the specific project I want to publish, here for example "foo".

How do I setup a shortcut that automatically publishes the project "foo" without additional prompts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `org-publish` says:

> (org-publish PROJECT &optional FORCE ASYNC)
>
> Publish PROJECT.
>
> PROJECT is either a project name, as a string, or a project
>   alist (see `org-publish-project-alist' variable).

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-1") 
   (lambda () 
      (interactive) 
      (org-publish "foo")))
```

Comment: It does not work for me: "eval-region: Wrong number of arguments: ... ".

Comment: I would bind a function specific to a mode to that mode map so that it doesn't pollute the global key binding space. `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-1") (lambda () (interactive) (org-publish "foo")))`

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveKeybinding When passing arguments to a function in a binding, you need to wrap them up first in an `interactive` wrapper function or a temporary function `lambda` with `interactive`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi This works, thank you! Would you mind either editing this answer or posting a new one so that I can accept it?